# How to save HTML with div and html attributes Using Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

This is my HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Do I need to print my ticket?
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>No, showing your e-ticket on your phone is fine. However, printing your ticket can sometimes make the process of entering an event easier/faster. </p>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

need to save it into the database
when I save it CKEditor automatically convert `<div>` to `<p>`

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried and explain what issue you're experiencing. Currently, this question is too unclear, broad and unspecific.

Comment: CKEDITOR.replace('editor1').config.allowedContent = true;

Comment: where is your `JavaScript` code

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve data from this editor called `CkEditor` you have to use method `CKEDITOR.editor.getData`, which is an instance of the editor.

```
<script>
    var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    //Then write your code here to save it 
</script>
```

Comment: @SantanuAdak if this problem has been solved, then please mark this question "answered". So, that others can get benefit of it.